# How to maintain these flex elements inside a flexbox as a single line on different width?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I generate a html layout using jsx. But it should not matter because it is a flexbox question.

Here is the code:

```
return (
  <div className={styles.message}>
    Hello hello hello Today date is&nbsp;
    <span className={styles.date]}>
     27 mar 2017
    </span>.
    Bye Bye Bye Bye
  </div>
);
```

It is the output:

[image]

Here is css:

```
.message {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.date {
  color: #2AAEDF;
}
```

However when I resize the page to narrow width, the text becomes

[image]

I have tried to enclose the text 'hello...' and 'bye...' inside a `span` element but it does not make them behave like `inline` elements

How can I ensure the text stay on a line?

**EDIT**

This is the effect I would like to achieve:

[image]

Comment: Add `white-space: nowrap`. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ms4hp0v3/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It kinds of work. But now both end of the sentence are truncated (outside the view)

Comment: I'm not sure why you need flexbox here. This is quite easy without flexbox. Check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ms4hp0v3/1/)

Comment: I have clarified the layout I am after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add `flex-wrap: wrap;` to the `message` rule, which will make the last flex item to break line when there is no more space.

*Note, both the text before and after the `span` is treated as flex items, anonymous ones, hence this will work as if they were wrapped in an element of their own*

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yj1836gn/)

Stack snippet

```css
.message {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.date {
  color: #2AAEDF;
}
```

```html
<div class="message">
  Hello hello hello Today date is&nbsp;
  <span class="date">
     27 mar 2017
    </span>. Bye Bye Bye Bye
</div>
```